# Why don't I have SQL Profiler on SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (`Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )`)

However I cannot find the option to open [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

I was under the impression that this was installed with SSMS 2008?

Or do I have to download this seperately? If so, where can I download it from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SQL Server Profiler is an *optional* component of Management Studio. You may have to find and select it below "Performance Tools" during installation. Under default settings, it gets installed as

**Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\PROFILER.EXE**

Some time ago I had an installation where Profiler was already in there but just not registered in SSMS Tools menu. You may have to launch it separately, if that is the case.